# Provide a few examples of Boolean algebra where carrier is a finite set of finite sequences (ordered set)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I study Boolean Algebra and it is clear when: (carrier is a power set, union, intersection), (set of all divisors of n, lcm, gcd), (the set of propositional functions of n given variables, conjunction, disjunction) In all this examples it is easy to see that binary operations on carrier are commutative. It is because structure of a elements of carrier allows it: set does not have order (A union B = B union A), $4*5=5*4$, $prop_1 ∨ prop_2 = prop_2 ∨ prop_1$,…

If we have a set of ordered sequences like $\{(1,2,3), (4,5)…\}$ it is hard for me to imagine commutative binary operations on this set.

Can you please suggest a few examples of Boolean Algebras where carrier is a set of sequences?

I am interested in a simple examples: finite set of strictly increasing, finite sequences. It is not important for a set to contain all sequences. It will be used as examples for teaching.

Comment: When saying 'ordered sequences', do you mean strictly increasing sequences? Does your set containt _all_ 'ordered' sequences or only some of them? Are its elements finite sequences only? Is the set itself finite or infinite?

Comment: @CiaPan thank you for relevant suggestions. I have updated a question.

Comment: If you allow a set of _all_ increasing sequences (including the degenerate empty one) of all natural numbers or just those from some interval, then every sequence would be an obvious representation of some set of natural numbers and you'll get algebra of sets. But I can't see an answer for an _arbitrary_ set of arbitrary sequences. The Wikipedia article [Boolean algebra (structure) # Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)#Examples) says the smallest Boolean algebra after {0,1} has four elements, so I understand there is no B.a. on e.g. a 3-element set...